# Selection of a row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to select a row where age is NaN in Pandas
`df[df['age']==np.nan]`

This does not return anything. But my dataset has a row where age is NaN

Comment: `df[pd.isnull(df['age'])]`

Comment: Use `df['df['age'].isna()]`

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'age': [15,np.nan, 30, 40]})
print(df)

    age
0  15.0
1   NaN
2  30.0
3  40.0
```

`df['age'].isna()` will give True for the rows that are nan:

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
```

Then you can find the rows and their values (which is nan) by using `df[df['age'].isna()]`:

```
   age
1  NaN
```